# digispark pin mode input_pullup reading low on pin 1

Tags: debugging

I have a [Digispark dev board](http://digistump.com/products/1) that I am using with the Arduino IDE.

I have set Pin 1 `HIGH` with `pinmode(1, INPUT_PULLUP)` and the LED attached turns on but when I perform a `digitalRead(1)`, I get a `LOW` response.

Is it because the LED in turning on is pulling the pin low?? And if so would de-soldering the SMD LED be a solution to making this pin available?

Actually I have performed the same thing on pins 0,2,3 (ie. with pullups) and all pins read as high except pin 1.

Comment: Sounds likely that the LED is loading a weak internal pullup to an intermediate value.  Try measuring the voltage and comparing to the data sheet VIH and VIL.  And then don't go there - intermediate values stress typical digital inputs and waste power.  Either use a pullup strong enough to drive the LED, or place a buffer amplifier or transistor between the weakly pulled up input and the LED (perhaps you can move the LED to another pin and drive it in software)

Comment: adding a schematic here will be helpful!

Comment: @Dhans - hardly needed, it would just show an LED connected to a pin.  Everything interesting is in the programmable *configuration* rather than the fixed topology.

Comment: Vf of the LED is a critical factor and Rs if any

Comment: Yup. I imagined and got it...I also suspect the pin's PULL_UP status!

Comment: A 2V Red LED on a 5V weak pullup will read as low

Comment: /When connecting a sensor to a pin configured with INPUT_PULLUP, the other end should be connected to ground. In the case of a simple switch, this causes the pin to read HIGH when the switch is open, and LOW when the switch is pressed./ this is the info from arduino website. Since the LED you connected with that pin closes the circuit, you may get a status as low.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74662/discussion-between-tonym-and-chris-stratton).

Answer (score 1):

You have effectively set up this situation:

[image: LED on input pin 1]

The current through the LED will be roughly:

```
5 / 30000 = 0.167 mA
```

The LED will light dimly. The voltage drop over a red LED is normally around 2V but at that current I measured 1.5V on a test setup.

The 150 ohm resistor (or whatever you are using, if anything) won't make much difference to that voltage. Therefore there is 1.5V on the input pin.

When you do a digital read you are reading 1.5V. Assuming your Vcc is 5V, then the Attiny85 datasheet specifies that a low reading is from \$-0.5V\$ to \$0.3 * Vcc\$ (ie. up to 1.5V) and a high reading is from \$0.6 * Vcc\$ (3V) to \$Vcc + 0.5\$.

Therefore the input pin reads LOW.

---

> Therefore removing the SMD LED should allow the pin to rise to the pull up value and should then read HIGH on the digitalRead(1)

Yes, removing the LED will stop that current flow to ground.

Comment: In a nutshell, the current prefers low resistance path; in this case, LED with 150-ohm resistance is the path for current flow which is grounded. Hence, you read it's status as 'LOW'.

Comment: Thank you, you have confirmed what I had suspected. Therefore removing the SMD LED should allow the pin to rise to the pull up value and should then read HIGH on the digitalRead(1) ?

Comment: Yes, I have amended the answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

The Digispark is a neat little PCB based on the Atmel (Microchip) ATtiny85.

[image: Digispark]

Pin 1 actually has a LED attached to it as part of the PCB circuit as you can see on the diagram below:

[image: Digispark schematic]

The pull-up is only weak on these chips. According to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf) for the ATtiny85, the inputs are pulled high using a 20k-50k resistor.

The LED is the cause of your issues. Simply desolder it and you will be able to use pin 1 as you wish.

---

Images courtesy of [Nick Gammon](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/20270/19409)

Comment: Thank you, a very complete and concise answer, the iron is warming up as i type. Stuart